# Flag weight color

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, flag-weight

Maybe flag weight should have the same color indicators like we have in «accept rate»? Not sure for others, but every time I open Stack Overflow in the morning, and that half second until I switch my brain into English mode, I think: «oh, I have something red on my profile. Red is bad... wait no, it's my flag weight, and it's 260, it's actually not bad».
So should it be red, gray, green or should it stay red as «real name» and «email» to show that nobody see this information except the owner of the page?

Comment: Flag weight? On profile? Where do you see that? Why don't I see that?

Comment: @fretje look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight look part «When can I view my own flag weight?»

Comment: ok, seems I'm not outside of the middleband then... oh well... thanks for the info anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colour choice was made to reflect the fact that it is private data, but I'm open to input here. Then, your email is in red, and (checks audit) you don't change that daily...

Comment: yes i understand that this is part of private data, and mentioned this in my question. But it's also a value that has different states (like less than 100 and more than 100). Or maybe it should be a link which points to meta page «what-is-flag-weight». Not sure, maybe i just in the critical mood.

Comment: yes I agree the flag weight label should match the email label color.  But the email and real name values are not in red.  So maybe the flag weight should just be black in color.